# How to support large requests when Azure API Management and the web app are using client certificate authentication?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, client-certificates

It is a known issue that client certificate authentication has problems with large requests.

The article here describes two possible solutions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/posting-a-large-file-can-fail-if-you-enable-client-certificates

1. Establish the connection first with a HEAD request
2. Set the Expect: 100-continue header for the request

It's easy to implement if we use our own HTTP client. But what if the web app is called through Azure API Management, which is configured to send the client certificate? Is there any way to make API Management use one of the workarounds mentioned in the article? Some setting or a custom policy maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to make it work with APIM:

1. Make your webapp request certificate when connection is established: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth This way certificate will be provided by APIM before HTTP request is sent and issue should be mitigated. The side effect is that if you were to open such web app in browser, browser will display certificate request UI.
2. You can use set-header policy in apim to set "Expect" header to "100-continue" value on backend request. In general, this affects API performance (issue not specific to APIM), as client will have to wait for explicit 100-continue response before starting payload transfer.

Comment: Thank you, `set-header` solution in the `inbound` policy section seems to work. I was not sure if it APIM internal HTTP client is smart enough to process `Expect: 100-continue` the same way as .NET HTTP client does, but APIM seems to be able to deal with it the same way and now large requests are coming through.